# Understanding rsh

Tags: remote-desktop, shell

I appreciate your help in my understanding of RSH-

Question related to RSH -

RSH is a terminal service which faciliates in remote logging / log off etc  ?

SSH is the terminology associated  with unix / linux only ? or for windows also ?

SSH can be used insteaf of RSH since it is secure ( the credentials etc are encrypted ).

Can I use ssh programmatically in c# to remote log off ?

Comment: RSH (probably) means "remote shell," SSH stands for "secure shell."  SSH is encrypted, RSH is not.  And as SSH can be used to execute commands on a remote host, you could use it to code a log off program in C#, I suppose.

Comment: There is nothing rsh can do, that ssh cannot, except communicate with leftover unix boxen from the 1980's.

Comment: `rsh` these days stands for `R`emote `S`ecurity `H`ole. All you really need to know about it is how to make sure it's disabled.  `ssh` does everything `rsh` ever did, better, and securely.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of SSH as RSH with added features, and most importantly, encryption.  Syntactically, they are extremely similar, in most, if not all, cases SSH simply has more options in addition to the commands for RSH.

SSH can still be used programmatically depending on what you're trying to do.

SSH is primarily seen on Linux, but you can install SSH servers on windows machines, particularly those running Cygwin.

Above all, RSH should be considered extremely insecure when compared to strong encryption of SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So to log off a windows user session remotely , what should I be using ( If I do not want to install SSH server )

Comment: @fr dotnet  *sigh*  Terminal Services/Remote Desktop Manager.

Comment: @frdotnet - there are many ways to log off a user remotely. Perhaps you should specifically research that task, rather than trying to fit an old broken square peg through a shiny new round hole.